# linux anaconda environment doesn't install modules

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, pytest, virtual-environment

I have an anaconda virtual environment set up on a linux box.

The `dotenv` module wasn't installed, so I tried to install it. It installed successfully:

```
(virt_env_01) [jm@etl01 testing]$ conda install -c conda-forge python-dotenv    
## Package Plan ##
  environment location: /home/jm/anaconda3/envs/virt_env_01
  added / updated specs:
    - python-dotenv
...
Downloading and Extracting Packages
certifi-2018.4.16    |  142 KB | ############################################### | 100%
python-dotenv-0.8.2  |   18 KB | ############################################### | 100%
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
```

However, when I tried to run the python script using it, I got an error saying no module found.

```
(virt_env_01) [jm@etl01 testing]$ pytest sql_server_tests.py
platform linux -- Python 3.6.3, pytest-3.2.1, py-1.4.34, pluggy-0.4.0
...
Traceback:
sql_server_tests.py:3: in <module>
    import dotenv
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv'
```

Can someone explain what I've done wrong?

EDIT:

I am running Pytest above. So I tried Python and it works fine. Could pytest be installed outside the virtual environment or something? I don't know how that all works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The pytest module was out of date.

After I ran `conda install pytest` it worked fine.

Comment: `pytest` does not installs `dotenv`

Answer (score 0):

`conda install -c conda-forge python-dotenv` installs the `dotenv`

another available installation with help of *anaconda package manager* is `conda install -c travis dotenv`, but it is not compatible with `python 3`